# Regex to match specific word within comma separated with or without hyphen

Tags: php, regex

This is my data

```
ZP-S,ZB-MA-S,ZB,ZB-MA-M,ZB-MA-B,ZP,PY,ZB-ME-S,ZB-ME-M,PY,ZB-ME-B,PY-S,PY-M,PY-B,ZP-B,ZB-MA-S-LS-MLE-PES
```

This is my regex, which I tried

```
(^|,)(ZB)-?[^,]+(,|$)
```

my intention here is to check whether within comma separated list has word which starts with **`(ZB)`** can contain `( hypen and [A-Za-z0-9_]+)` recursively

Expected match are as follows

```
ZB-MA-S
ZB
ZB-MA-M
ZB-MA-B
ZB-ME-S
ZB-ME-M
ZB-ME-B
ZB-MA-S-LS-MLE-PES
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/pjje20/4)

```
ZB[^,]*(?=,?)
```

What I am looking for is to match any comma separated value that starts with the searched string `ZB` and keep matching as long as I don't hit a `,`.

Hope this helps

Comment: the lookahead is entirely unnecessary

Answer (score 3):

**This should do it**

***`(ZB[\w\-]*)`***

***Demo here

https://regex101.com/r/D1dRxd/3***

> [image]

***`ZB`*** matches the characters **`ZB`** literally (case sensitive)
**`\w`** matches any word character (equal to [a-zA-Z0-9_])
**`\-`** matches the character - literally (case sensitive)
**`*`** Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed

> [image]

Comment: Not matching ZB without hyphen

Comment: (ZB[\w\-]*) fixes the 'ZB' match

Answer (score 2):

Try `ZB[a-zA-Z0-9\-\_]*`

This will match all alphanumeric characters, underscore, and hyphen following ZB